# CSS identify div child of child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html code

```
<div class='father'>
    <div>
        <div>
             Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot modify the html source, so I was trying to modify the attributes and style of the div containing "some text".

Could the syntax "div:nth-child" help me?

I used to identify a child item of a div but here I have to identify the child item of another child.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), to achieve this. [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/DvLLN/)

```
.father > div > div {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
.father>div>div
```

More people need to know about the `>` combinator!

Comment: You're right! But please understand that not everyone works with css, anyways, thank you very much! ;)